# How to disable Pinch gesture completely in iphone?

Tags: iphone, zooming, gesture, pinch

I cannot use userInteractionEnabled as it is a map and I need it to be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route me doesn't use gesture recognizers. Look at the event handling section of RMMapView to see how they handle touch events. I saw a couple references to "zoom" in there.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to turn off pinching on a map, then why not just set the `zoomEnabled` property of `MKMapView` to `NO`?

Comment: I am using an offline custom map from Route-Me. I need zoom enabled but only by bar buttons, not by pinching.

Comment: Do you have access to their source code? Even if not, take a look at the `gestureRecognizers` on the view and search through for a pinch one. Then disable it. Maybe that will work?

Comment: I have the header files which implement touch methods. I cant seem to find the pinch related codes though

Comment: Have you tried looking at its gesture recognisers? I.e. the `gestureRecognizers` property of the view. If it's handling the touches itself then you might be out of luck this way.